# Assigning value to a variable in if statement in Perl

Tags: perl

I get a warning `Use of ininitialized value in regexp compilation` when trying to assignment new value to a variable from `if` statement. Why this warning occur?

My code:

```
my $command; 

if ($number == 1) {
    $command = $ARGV[0];
} elsif ($number == 2) {
    $command = $ARGV[1]; 
}

my @values = split(undef, $command); # error here
print "$values[0]\n";
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialised value in regexp compilation at ./file.pl
```

For example, with input `i/3542/$` (as just one argument), expected output would be just `i`.

Comment: Hmm it's not really surprising that `undef` is uninitialized, is it? You presumably want to split by the empty string, `... split('', ...`?

Comment: @stickybit I want to split by every element, no every empty string.

Comment: That's a very vague description... You mean you want to split the string into its individual characters? That's exactly what `split('', ...` does...

Comment: @stickybit that worked, thank you! I got `split(undef, ...)` solution from here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-split-function/. Looks like its not a correct one.

Comment: That geeksforgeeks article also shows the error you saw. IMHO geeksforgeeks is just garbage.

Comment: geeksforgeeks has clearly been putting a lot of money into showing up at the top of search results, but I don't think I've ever seen a correct answer on their site. Just ignore them. Forever.

Comment: It looks like they're the new w3schools. Best refer to the actual manual instead. [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org).

Comment: Fair attempt on your part, but this `split` with `undef` is one of the more horrific things I've seen. It would never even cross my mind to do something like that.  Mistakes happen, but one like that really looks bad for that website. And there are really good resources around anyway, like the official docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing at all to do with your `if` statement. I assume that the full error message tells you that the problem is on the line:

```
my @values = split(undef, $command);
```

Here's [the documentation for the `split()` command](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split). It says the command takes the following forms:

> split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT
> split /PATTERN/,EXPR
> split /PATTERN/
> split

You're using the second option here - where the function takes two arguments a regex (or "pattern") and a string (or "expr"). Your warning says "uninitialised value in regexp compilation", so it seems obvious that the problem is with the first argument (the regex), not the second one.

Using `undef` as a regex makes no sense. But Perl will make the best of the situation and treats the `undef` as an empty string (after displaying the warning you've seen). You can remove the warning by replacing `undef` with a real regex - one that just contains an empty string.

```
my @values = split(//, $command);
```

**Note:** `split()` will usually accept a string as its first argument and silently convert it to a regex. I find it's more self-documenting if you always explicitly use a regex here - which is why I've used `split(//, ...)` instead of the `split('', ...)` suggested in a couple of comments.

Comment: Perhaps also worth emphasizing is the special pattern, `split ' ', $string`, using just a space between quotes (`' '`).  This splits the string by (any amount of) whitespace, and discards leading and trailing spaces; thus it breaks the string into words.  Very often very useful, so it's default: `... split;` means `... split ' ', $_`